# Form validation using javascript (Registration Form with formatting)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, registration

I am trying to validate each field and display appropriate error messages using defined formatting. The username displayed appropriate error message, but the rest of the code is not "working". The email field was working, but after I store the variables atEmail and dotEmail, it didn't work anymore. I have been trying at this for a couple of days already. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

function validateForm() {

```
var firstPassword = document.myForm.passwordOne.value;
var secondPassword = document.myForm.passwordTwo.value; 
var emailID = document.myForm.email.value;
var alphaNumeric = /^[\w ]+$/;
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var atEmail = emailID.indexOf("@");
var dotEmail = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
var phone = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;

 if(!alphaNumeric.test(document.myForm.userName.value)) {
    alert( "Please enter letters and numbers only!" );
    document.myForm.userName.focus() ;
    return false;
 }

 if(firstPassword.value.length < 8) {
    alert( "Password must be at least 8 characters" );
    document.myForm.passwordOne.focus() ;
    return false;
 }

 if(document.myForm.firstPassword.value != document.myForm.secondPassword.value ) {
    alert( "Password must match!" );
    document.myForm.passwordTwo.focus() ;
    return false;
 }

 if(!letters.match(document.myForm.firstName.value)) {
    alert( "Your first name should only contain letters!" );
    document.myForm.firstName.focus() ;
    return false;
 }

 if(!letters.match(document.myForm.lastName.value)) {
    alert( "Your last name should only contain letters!" );
    document.myForm.lastName.focus() ;
    return false;
 }

 if (atEmail < 1 || ( dotEmail - atEmail < 2 )) {
    alert("Please enter valid email address format: xxx@xxx.xxx");
    document.myForm.email.focus() ;
    return false;
 }

 if(phonenumber.value.match(phone)) {
    alert( "Please enter valid phone number format:(xxx) xxx-xxxx" );
    document.myForm.phonenumber.focus() ;
    return false;
 }

 if((document.myForm.signUpNewletter[0].checked == false) &&(document.myForm.signUpNewletter[1].checked == false )) {
    alert( "Please check yes or no!" );
    document.myForm.signUpNewsletter.focus() ;
    return false;
 }

 return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is correct?

```
if(document.myForm.firstPassword.value != document.myForm.secondPassword.value ) {
```

You have already defined `firstPassword` and `secondPassword` variables, then  why use them in `document.myForm.firstPassword` and `document.myForm.secondPassword`